# Save file to azure storage using streams not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I would like to  save a file into stream container from a stream using [azure-storage package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage)

Here's how I get stream

```
let request = rp(options).on("response", async (response) => {
  if (response.statusCode === 200) {
    await insertFile("TTSOutput.wav", request, request.length);
}
```

Here's how I save it into Azure

```
var insertFile = async function (blobName, stream) {
  try {
    blobService = await azure.createBlobService(connStr);

    blobService.createContainerIfNotExists(
      containerName,
      {
        publicAccessLevel: "blob",
      },
      (err, result, response) => {
        if (!err) {
          let resultstream = blobService.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob(
            containerName,
            blobName
          );
          stream.pipe(resultstream);
        }
      }
  );
}
```

Actually only container is created but no file is get uploaded

Comment: Did you mean to write `await insertFile("TTSOutput.wav", response, response.length);` instead of `await insertFile("TTSOutput.wav", request, request.length);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below to upload a .wav file from Azure TTS API:

```
let request = rp(options)
        .on('response', (response) => {
            if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                tempFilePath = 'd:/temp.wav'
                request.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(tempFilePath));
                insertFile('TTSOutput.wav',fs.createReadStream(tempFilePath)).then(function(){
                    fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath)
                    console.log("uploaded")})
            }
        });
```

`insertFile` function:

```
const {
    BlobServiceClient
  } = require('@azure/storage-blob');

var conn_str = '<storage account connection string>'
var container = '<your container name>'

async function insertFile(blobName, stream) {
   
    BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(conn_str).getContainerClient(container).getBlockBlobClient(blobName).uploadStream(stream)

}
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean upload stream to Azure Storage Blob, please try [`createBlockBlobFromStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-storage/azurestorage.services.blob.blobservice.blobservice?view=azure-node-legacy#createBlockBlobFromStream_string__string__stream_Readable__number__CreateBlockBlobRequestOptions__ErrorOrResult_BlobResult__) method.

```
var myStream = getSomeStream(); // Assume getSomeStream() returns a readable stream
var myStreamLength = getSomeStreamLength(); // return the length of stream
blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream(
    containerName,
    'stream-blob-name',
    myStream,
    myStreamLength,
    function(error, result, response){
        if(error){
            console.log("Couldn't upload stream");
            console.error(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Stream uploaded successfully');
        }
    });
```